# SelectedIndexChanged event handler getting old index

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm handling the `onSelectIndexChanged` event. An event is raised when the DropDownList selection changes. the problem is that the DropDownList still returns the old values for `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the DropDownList definition from the aspx file:

```
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 1em 0px 0px;">
    <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: top;">Route:</span>
    <asp:DropDownList id="Select1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="index_changed" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Here is the DropDownList `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler:

```
protected void index_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal( Select1.SelectedValue );
    Literal1.Text = d.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have any code in page load that is by chance re-defaulting the value to the first value?

When the page reloads do you see the new value?

Comment: yeah, that's the first thing I thought of as well.

Comment: I checked and found to my surprise that I did have some code in Page_Load that is re-defaulting the value. Thank you Mitchel!

Comment: Five years later, and still relevant. The 'gotcha' is that is that `runat="server"` will trigger post, calling `Page_Load` and the whole shebang, which may not be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AJAX you may also be doing a callback, not a full postback.  In that case you may want to use this in your page load method:

```
        if (!IsCallback && !IsPostBack)
        {
            // Do your page setup here
        }
```

Comment: Is this actually true? I'm pretty sure that `IsPostBack` will return `true` in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

add this:
if page.isnotpostback {

}
around your code to bind the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem obvious, but anyway.
Do you initialize this dropdown with an initial value in some other event handler like OnLoad ?
If so you should check if that event is risen by a postback or by the first load. So you should have something like

```
if(!IsPostback) d.SelectedValue = "Default"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have items copied throughout your datasource for the drop down list?